# Spark create a dataframe from multiple lists/arrays

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

So, I have 2 lists in Spark(scala). They both contain the same number of values. The first list `a` contains all strings and the second list `b` contains all Long's.

```
a: List[String] = List("a", "b", "c", "d")
b: List[Long] = List(17625182, 17625182, 1059731078, 100)
```

I also have a schema defined as follows:

```
val schema2=StructType(
  Array(
    StructField("check_name", StringType, true),
    StructField("metric", DecimalType(38,0), true)
  )
)
```

What is the best way to convert my lists to a single dataframe, that has schema `schema2` and the columns are made from `a` and `b` respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `RDD[Row]` and convert to Spark dataframe with the given schema:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize(a.zip(b).map(x => Row(x._1, BigDecimal(x._2)))), 
    schema2
)

df.show
+----------+----------+
|check_name|    metric|
+----------+----------+
|         a|  17625182|
|         b|  17625182|
|         c|1059731078|
|         d|       100|
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Dataset:

```
import spark.implicits._
case class Schema2(a: String, b: Long)

val el = (a zip b) map { case (a, b) => Schema2(a, b)}
val df = spark.createDataset(el).toDF()
```